# How to write parse data to a JSON file using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to create an API to convert a pdf file into JSON. Data I am getting after parsing pdf file is in comma separated value. I am using Nodejs pdf2json package.
Data what I m getting after parsing pdf file:

```
"val a: 1, val b: 2, val c, vald: 3, 4, 5, 6, val e: 7,"
```

Desired Output:

```
{
"val a" : 1,
"val b" : 2,
"val c" : "",
"vald" : "3,4,5,6",
"val e": 7
}
```

The code I am using:

```js
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    upload = require('express-fileupload'),
    http = require('http').Server(app).listen(8080),
    PDFParser = require("pdf2json"),
    fs = require('fs');

console.log("Server started on port 8080");

//pdf parser
let pdfParser = new PDFParser(this, 1);


//express file uploader                
app.use(upload());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    if (req.files) {
        var file = req.files.filename,
            filename = file.name;
        pdfParser.parseBuffer(file.data);


        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataError", errData => console.error(errData.parserError));
        pdfParser.on("pdfParser_dataReady", pdfData => {
            var output = JSON.stringify(pdfParser.getRawTextContent()).split(/\\r\\n/);
            fs.writeFile('data2toJson.json', output, 'utf8');
            console.log("hellow" + Date());
        });

        res.send("done");
    }
})
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
    <input type="file" name="filename">
    <input type="submit" value="upload">
</form>
```

Comment: What are your findings? What is the result of the above code?

Comment: I have given what is the result of above code in the question

Comment: Sorry my bad, read too quickly

Comment: @tgdn its OK I need some help in forming regex in split method, I think so that can solve this issue, but m not sure

Comment: @tgdn Thanks, I have read that question before, but it is not helping me in solving my problem

Comment: what do you get when you log `output`

Comment: @turmuka log output have given in question

Comment: Is the input pdf containing JSON data as well?or some other data?

Comment: what do you get when you only log `pdfParser.getRawTextContent().split(/\\r\\n/)` ?

Comment: @turmuka output: "val a : 1\r\nval b: 2 ..."       and so on

Comment: I see, so it's not an object, I think the problem occurs with `getRawTextContent()` which converts it to plain string,

Comment: what happens when you try `fs.writeFile("data2toJson.json", JSON.stringify(pdfData));`

Comment: @turmuka it gives jargon values which cannot be read by human

Comment: Thanx everyone here, I didn't get 100% output, but yet I tried regex instead of split to get 75% of values require from pdf, the regex I used - `var re = new RegExp(key + ':(.*?)\\\\', "i");
                    return output.match(re)[1].trim();`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the expected output as per your question.
Try below solution

hope this will get you going :)

NOTE: you should try an optimized solution to do the same.

```js
var input = "val a: 1, val b: 2, val c, vald: 3, 4, 5, 6, val e: 7,";
var keys = input.match(/(val([a-z0-9\s]+):)|(val([a-z0-9\s]+),)/g)
var output = {};
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  input = input.slice(keys[i].length);
  if (i < keys.length - 1)
    var val = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(keys[i + 1]));
  else
    var val = input;
  input = input.slice(val.length);
  val = val.trim();

  if (val.lastIndexOf(",") == val.length - 1) {
    val = val.substr(0, val.length - 1)
  }
  output[keys[i].replace(":", "").replace(",", "")] = val;
}
console.log(output)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I got little idea from your code, I have used regex and match method instead of split, m still working on issue, once it gets resolve will update here